# Integrate Rack Mini Profiler gem into Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling, rack, rack-mini-profiler

I am using or rather want to use the Rack Mini Profiler gem in an Rails-app with an asset pipeline. My Problem is, that since this gem is not meant to be integrated in an app with a pipeline, the static files from it aren't loaded, especially the include js. Is somebody using this gem in such an app or is there a general approach, that might work here?

Thanks ahead,
stiller-leser